# Why am I getting an exception when filling the database with test data (EF Core - ASP-NET Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am getting an exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I can't understand, why. What's wrong with my connections between tables? I wanted to establish a relationship between the "Country" and "Company" tables in a one-to-many relationship, to avoid duplicating countries in the Company table ( This is what the table looked like before - Image3. I want to create 3 table.

Information about exception:
[Image1](https://ibb.co/vvSZLy3)

Information2:
[Image2](https://ibb.co/HNCJm9R)

The table before:
[Image3](https://ibb.co/XpKTvbr)

An exception occurs in the tables: "Product" - "Company" - "Country".
Seed Database:

```
using E_Store2021.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace E_Store2021.Data
{
    public static class ApplicationDbContextSeed
    {
        public static async Task SeedAsync(ApplicationDbContext _context, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                await SeedCategoriesAsync(_context);

                await SeedSubCategories(_context);

                await SeedCountry(_context);

                await SeedCompany(_context);

                await SeedProduct(_context);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ApplicationDbContext>();
                log.LogError(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        private static async Task SeedCategoriesAsync(ApplicationDbContext _context)
        {
            if (_context.Categories.Any()) return;
            var categories = new List<Category>()
            {
                new Category
                {
                    Description = "Some category",
                    CategoryName = "Electronics",
                    ImagePath = "category_1.webp"
                },
                new Category
                {
                    Description = "Some category",
                    CategoryName = "Computers",
                    ImagePath = "category_2.webp"
                },
                new Category
                {
                    Description = "Some category",
                    CategoryName = "Music",
                    ImagePath = "category_3.webp"
                },
                new Category
                {
                    Description = "Some category",
                    CategoryName = "Software",
                    ImagePath = "category_4.webp"
                },
                new Category
                {
                    Description = "Some category",
                    CategoryName = "Arts",
                    ImagePath = "category_5.webp"
                },
                new Category
                {
                    Description = "Some category",
                    CategoryName = "Games",
                    ImagePath = "category_6.webp"
                },
            };
            _context.Categories.AddRange(categories);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        private static async Task SeedSubCategories(ApplicationDbContext _context)
        {
            if (_context.SubCategories.Any()) return;
            var categories = await _context.Categories.ToListAsync();
            var subCategories = new List<SubCategory>
            {
                new SubCategory
                {
                    CategoryID =  categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryName == "Electronics").CategoryID,
                    SubCategoryName = "Camera",
                    Description = "Some"
                },
                new SubCategory
                {
                    CategoryID =  categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryName == "Electronics").CategoryID,
                    SubCategoryName = "Phones",
                    Description = "Some"
                },
                new SubCategory
                {
                    CategoryID =  categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryName == "Electronics").CategoryID,
                    SubCategoryName = "Headphones",
                    Description = "Some"
                },
                new SubCategory
                {
                    CategoryID =  categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryName == "Electronics").CategoryID,
                    SubCategoryName = "Video Game Consoles && Accessories",
                    Description = "Some"
                },
            };
            _context.SubCategories.AddRange(subCategories);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        private static async Task SeedProduct(ApplicationDbContext _context)
        {
            if (_context.Products.Any()) return;
            var subCategories = await _context.SubCategories.ToListAsync();
            var companies = await _context.Companies.ToListAsync();
            var products = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product
                {
                    ProductName = "iPhone 12 Pro Max",
                    SubCategoryID = subCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Phones").SubCategoryID,
                    UnitPrice = 1695.66,
                    ImagePath = "iphone12.webp",
                    Description = "Some phone",
                    OnSale = true,
                    Star = 5,
                    Quantity = 10,
                    CompanyID = companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CompanyName == "Apple").CompanyID,
                },
                new Product
                {
                    ProductName = "iPhone 11 Pro Max",
                    SubCategoryID = subCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Phones").SubCategoryID,
                    UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                    ImagePath = "iphone11.jpg",
                    Description = "Some phone",
                    OnSale = false,
                    Star = 5,
                    Quantity = 10,
                    CompanyID = companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CompanyName == "Apple").CompanyID,
                },
                new Product
                {
                    ProductName = "Xiaomi 9 Pro",
                    SubCategoryID = subCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Phones").SubCategoryID,
                    UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                    ImagePath = "iphone11.jpg",
                    Description = "Some phone",
                    OnSale = false,
                    Star = 5,
                    Quantity = 10,
                    CompanyID = companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CompanyName == "Xiaomi").CompanyID,
                },
                new Product
                {
                    ProductName = "Canon PowerShot SX540 Digital Camera",
                    SubCategoryID = subCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Camera").SubCategoryID,
                    UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                    ImagePath = "canon_sx540.jpg",
                    Description = "Some phone",
                    OnSale = false,
                    Star = 5,
                    Quantity = 10,
                    CompanyID = companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CompanyName == "Canon").CompanyID,
                },
                new Product
                {
                    ProductName = "Panasonic LUMIX FZ300",
                    SubCategoryID = subCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Camera").SubCategoryID,
                    UnitPrice = 397,
                    ImagePath = "panasonic_fz300.jpg",
                    Description = "Some phone",
                    OnSale = false,
                    Star = 5,
                    Quantity = 10,
                    CompanyID = companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CompanyName == "Panasonic").CompanyID,
                },
                new Product
                {
                    ProductName = "4K Digital Camera 48MP Camera",
                    SubCategoryID = subCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Camera").SubCategoryID,
                    UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                    ImagePath = "4k_digitalcamera_48mp.jpg",
                    Description = "Some phone",
                    Star = 4.5,
                    Quantity = 10,
                    CompanyID = companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CompanyName == "CEDITA").CompanyID,
                },
                new Product
                {
                    ProductName = "TOZO T10 Bluetooth 5.0", 
                    SubCategoryID = subCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Headphones").SubCategoryID,
                    UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                    ImagePath = "tozo_t10.jpg",
                    Description = "Some phone",
                    OnSale = false,
                    Star = 4.6,
                    Quantity = 10,
                    CompanyID = companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CompanyName == "TOZO").CompanyID,
                },
                new Product
                {
                    ProductName = "TOZO T6 True Wireless",
                    SubCategoryID = subCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Headphones").SubCategoryID,
                    UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                    ImagePath = "tozo_t6.jpg",
                    Description = "Some phone",
                    OnSale = false,
                    Star = 4.5,
                    Quantity = 10,
                    CompanyID = companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CompanyName == "TOZO").CompanyID,
                },
                new Product
                {
                    ProductName = "Razer Kraken Tournament Edition",
                    SubCategoryID = subCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Headphones").SubCategoryID,
                    UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                    ImagePath = "razer_kraken.jpg",
                    Description = "Some phone",
                    OnSale = false,
                    Star = 4.5,
                    Quantity = 10,
                    CompanyID = companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CompanyName == "Razer").CompanyID,
                },
                new Product
                {
                    ProductName = "Sony PlayStation 4 Pro (Red Dead Redemption 2 Bundle)",
                    SubCategoryID = subCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Video Game Consoles && Accessories").SubCategoryID,
                    UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                    ImagePath = "playstation-4.jpg",
                    Description = "Some phone",
                    OnSale = false,
                    Star = 4,
                    Quantity = 10,
                    CompanyID = companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CompanyName == "Sony").CompanyID,
                },
                new Product
                {
                    ProductName = "PlayStation 4 Pro 1TB Limited Edition",
                    SubCategoryID = subCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Video Game Consoles && Accessories").SubCategoryID,
                    UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                    ImagePath = "playstation-spider.jpg",
                    Description = "Some phone",
                    OnSale = false,
                    Star = 5,
                    Quantity = 10,
                    CompanyID = companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CompanyName == "Sony").CompanyID,
                },
            };

            _context.Products.AddRange(products);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        private static async Task SeedCompany(ApplicationDbContext _context)
        {
            if (_context.Companies.Any()) return;
            var countries = await _context.Countries.ToListAsync();
            List<Company> companies = new List<Company>
            {
                new Company
                {
                    CompanyName = "Apple",
                    Year = 1976,
                    CountryID = countries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CountryName == "USA").CountryID
                },
                new Company
                {
                    CompanyName = "Xiaomi",
                    Year = 2010,
                    CountryID = countries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CountryName == "China").CountryID
                },
                new Company
                {
                    CompanyName = "Canon",
                    Year = 1987,
                    CountryID = countries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CountryName == "China").CountryID
                },
                new Company
                {
                    CompanyName = "Panasonic",
                    Year = 1918,
                    CountryID = countries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CountryName == "Japan").CountryID
                },
                new Company
                {
                    CompanyName = "CEDITA",
                    Year = 2005,
                    CountryID = countries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CountryName == "United Kingdom").CountryID
                },
                new Company
                {
                    CompanyName = "TOZO",
                    Year = 2016,
                    CountryID = countries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CountryName == "Spain").CountryID
                },
                new Company
                {
                    CompanyName = "Razer",
                    Year = 2010,
                    CountryID = countries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CountryName == "USA").CountryID
                },
                new Company
                {
                    CompanyName = "Sony",
                    Year = 2000,
                    CountryID = countries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CountryName == "Sony").CountryID
                },
            };
            _context.Companies.AddRange(companies);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        private static async Task SeedCountry(ApplicationDbContext _context)
        {
            if (_context.Countries.Any()) return;

            var countries = new List<Country>
            {
                new Country
                {
                    CountryName = "Spain"
                },
                new Country
                {
                    CountryName = "United Kingdom"
                },
                new Country
                {
                    CountryName = "Japan"
                },
                new Country
                {
                    CountryName = "China"
                },
                new Country
                {
                    CountryName = "USA"
                },
            };
            _context.Countries.AddRange(countries);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

Class Product:

```
using E_Store2021.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace E_Store2021.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)] 
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string ImagePath { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Price")]
        public double UnitPrice { get; set; }

        public bool OnSale { get; set; }

        public double Star { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public int? SubCategoryID { get; set; }

        public int? CompanyID { get; set; }

        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

        public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Class Company:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace E_Store2021.Models
{
    public class Company
    {
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }

        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        public int Year { get; set; }

        public int? CountryID { get; set; }

        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Class Country:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace E_Store2021.Models
{
    public class Country
    {

        public int CountryID { get; set; }

        public string CountryName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Looks like countries is not yet populated.  Since this is just seeding the database, why not use blocking methods instead of async?

Comment: companies in my case == null, although I filled in countries, in theory it should work, but ...

Comment: My guess is because it is running async that it is possible the context is saving while the other functions are attempting to grab values.

Comment: Maybe change the methods to synchronous?                 await SeedCountry(_context);

                await SeedCompany(_context);

                await SeedProduct(_context);

Comment: Didn't work....

Comment: Might be a mistyped country name.
CountryID = countries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CountryName == "Sony").CountryID   
Happens to the best of us! :)

Comment: Double check all of the Sub Category and Company names

Comment: All, I deleted the table and create again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the error:

```
new Company
                {
                    CompanyName = "Sony",
                    Year = 2000,
                    CountryID = countries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CountryName == "Sony").CountryID
                },
```

Comment: @Evgeny20 You have the error again. I remember your anoher error with the short fields. Now with the country name.

Comment: Yes, I'm so unlucky with mistakes and inattentive

Comment: Close the question or leave?

Comment: Did you fix Sony company? it could give your product error.

Comment: Yes, I fixed. I recreated table

Comment: I will delete this question if you have received a rating

Comment: Why? Typo can happen to everybody. I think I wouldn't be able to work in Visual Studio without Intellisence. I would have 2 typos  in each word. This is why the experienced programmers  don't use strings in the code, the prefer the string constants. It's very hard to find the error when it is a string typo.

Answer (score 2):

Declare your collection navigation properties like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; } = new HashSet<Product>();
```

So they start out empty, not null.